# Awk only prints (0, 1) if pattern, but I want to print the pattern

Tags: bash, unix, awk, pattern-matching

I'm new to AWK, I think is awesome, but I'm a noob.

I'm doing this:

```
awk '{print $1, $2 = /Pattern\w+/}' file
```

to this kind of data:

```
3145 wfgd4  2345 sdf 55667 PatternAHF34
3148 fh345  34f  PatternRT4555 NNN NNN
3158 57ggt  3458f 58886 PatternYT334 56YY
3165 rf3d4  2t45 sdf 55667 Potato
3188 fhrf5  34b  PatternRT8855 N3 NN55
3218 g7ggt  34ggf 5116 PatternYYY34 56YT
```

As you can see, the columns are not align.

What I want:

```
3145 PatternAHF34
3148 PatternRT4555
3158 PatternYT334
3165 
3188 PatternRT8855
3218 PatternYYY34
```

What i get:

```
3145 1
3148 1
3158 1
3165 0
3188 1
3218 1
```

Thanks everybody in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could say:

```
awk '{match($0, /Pattern\w+/)} { print $1, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' file
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
3145 PatternAHF34
3148 PatternRT4555
3158 PatternYT334
3165 
3188 PatternRT8855
3218 PatternYYY34
```

(Your example produces `0` and `1` because you assign `$2` to the result of the pattern match.)

You might also want to refer to [Built-in variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables).

Comment: +1 but you should mention that the solution is gawk-specific courtesy of `\w` which is gawk shorthand for the POSIX `[[:alnum:]_]`. To me it seems like the more natural syntax than shown with 2 separate action blocks would be a single action block `awk '{ match($0, /Pattern\w+/); print $1, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' file` but it'll work either way.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
awk -f f.awk file
```

where `f.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {
    pat="Pattern\\w+"
}

{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ pat) {
            print $1, $i
            next
        }
    }
    print $1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{a=$1;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i~/Pattern/){a=a " " $i}};print a}'
```

The way to read this is as follows. For every line, grab the first field, then loop through all fields on that line, and if you find a field that matches, grab that too, then print whatever you've got..

Answer (score 1):

The other answers present how to achieve what you want. Let me explain why your script is not working.
The expression `/Pattern\w+/` will return `1`(true) if the lines matches the pattern and `0`(false) otherwize.

So the expression:

```
{print $1, $2 = /Pattern\w+/}
```

is more or less equivalent to

```
{
  test = /Pattern\w+/;
  print $1, test  
}
```